# how to get image from Android imageview and storing into db

Tags: java, android, performance, web-services, rest

How to get image from android image view and how to store that value into database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first get drawble from imageview

```
Drawable d = yourimageview.getDrawable();
```

and then convert into byte array to store into database

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);
Bitmap bmp = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(bmp.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] arr = stream.toByteArray();
```

now you can easily store byte array i.e arr into database as blob.

Comment: I used this.but i didn't store correct value                                                                  Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
  logo = bos.toByteArray();

Comment: and how u store it in datbase.?

Comment: i am storing like
 public void postHotel(MultivaluedMap<String,String> hotelParams) throws SQLException{
   
  byte[] imgLogo=hotelParams.getFirst("hotel_logo").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
  
  System.out.println("Successully Comes into post="+imgLogo.length);
  
  
  stmt.executeUpdate("insert into hotel(hotel_logo)values('"+imgLogo+"');");
   
  System.out.println("Saave Successfully...,");
  
 }

Comment: can you please update your question. im unable to see code properly